# Addressing more than 4GB of GPU memory - how does that work?

Tags: gpu, 32-bit, memory-limit, addressing, tesla

Typical GPUs today are mostly 32-bit-oriented. While they can do double precision, the ALUs take 32-bit integers basically, thread indices and grid sizes are 32-bit, and (I'm assuming) pseudo-pointers correspond to 32-bit unsigned physical addresses as well.

However, some GPUs (Teslas, GTX Titans) come with 6GB, 8GB, 12GB of memory.

Well, how does that work? I mean, can you address more than 4GB at once? If so, how? Can you do a[i] = 123 with i being of type unsigned long int? Or is it some segment-offset thing like in the good old days of 8086? Or maybe each kernel *individually* can address only 4GB, but different kernels can address more?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it turns out that GPU pointers (at least in NVIDIA GPUs and probably in AMD's as well) are 64-bits. So there's no problem with addressing 4GB, 40 GB, 400 GB or 4 Million GB. It's only for 32-bit platforms that there might be legacy support for 32-bit pointers.